# ESP8266 - PubSubClient - Message character limit

Tags: json, arduino, mqtt, esp8266, nodemcu

I am unable to send messages over a certain limit. I have looked at the [docs](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api.html#configoptions) and have already tried to redefine the max packet size:

```
#define MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE 512
```

I've even tried increasing the limit to ridiculous limits and still the message is ignored. The size of my message is 253 characters in compressed JSON format:

```
{ "code_gc": [ 38000,1,69,342,171,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,63,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,63,21,63,21,63,21,63,21,63,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,63,21,63,21,63,21,1829,342,85,21,3663 ] }
```

It's an IR remote for anyone wondering what I'm building.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I should do to allow this message through? My only thought now is to scrap MQTT and create a REST server, which I don't want to do as MQTT is a lot faster in my experience..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was advised by the repository owner of `PubSubClient`, I needed to change the `MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE` inside the source file of `PubSubClient` as it cannot be redefined.

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

To change this value you can use this two solution

first, define  `MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE` before including SubPubClient

this code in `SubPubClint.h`, case prioritize your define variable

```
#ifndef MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE
#define MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE 255
#endif
```

second, and better solution is use this function to reset buffer size (default value is 255)

```cpp
boolean PubSubClient::setBufferSize(uint16_t size)
```

like it :

```cpp
mqtt.setBufferSize(newBufferValue);
```